# How to convince nvcc to use 128-bit wide loads?

Tags: vector, cuda, bandwidth, nvcc

I have a kernel that needs to apply a stencil operation on an array and store the result on another array. The stencil could be expressed in a function as:

```
float stencil(const float* data)
{
    return *(data-1) + *(data+1);
}
```

I want every thread to produce 4 contiguous values of the output array by loading 6 contiguous values of the input array. By doing so I would be able to use the float4 type for loading and storing in chunks of 128 bytes. This is my program (you can download and compile it, but please consider the kernel in first place):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<thrust/host_vector.h>
#include<thrust/device_vector.h>

__global__ void kernel(const float* input, float* output, int size)
{
    int i = 4*(blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x);
    float values[6];
    float res[4];

    // Load values
    values[0] = *(input+i-1);
    *reinterpret_cast<float4*>(values+1) = *reinterpret_cast<const float4*>(input+i);
    values[5] = *(input+i+4);

    // Compute result
    res[0] = values[0]+values[2];
    res[1] = values[1]+values[3];
    res[2] = values[2]+values[4];
    res[3] = values[3]+values[5];

    // Store result
    *reinterpret_cast<float4*>(output+i) = *reinterpret_cast<const float4*>(res);
}

int main()
{
    // Parameters
    const int nBlocks = 8;
    const int nThreads = 128;
    const int nValues = 4 * nThreads * nBlocks;

    // Allocate host and device memory
    thrust::host_vector<float> input_host(nValues+64);
    thrust::device_vector<float> input(nValues+64), output(nValues);

    // Generate random input
    srand48(42);
    thrust::generate(input_host.begin(), input_host.end(), []{ return drand48()+1.; });
    input = input_host;

    // Run kernel
    kernel<<<nBlocks, nThreads>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(input.data()+32), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(output.data()), nValues);

    // Check output
    for (int i = 0; i < nValues; ++i)
    {
        float ref = input_host[31+i] + input_host[33+i];

        if (ref != output[i])
        {
            std::cout << "Error at " << i << " : " << ref << "  " << output[i] << "\n";
            std::cout << "Abort with errors\n";
            std::exit(1);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Success\n";
}
```

The program works perfectly.

I would expect the compiler to generate one `LD.E.128` instruction for the central part of the local array `values`, and the registers for this central part to be contiguous (e.g. R4, R5, R6, R7); to have two `LD.E` instructions for both ends of `values`; to have one `ST.E.128` for the `output` array.

What happens in reality is the following:

```
code for sm_21
    Function : _Z6kernelPKfPfi

    /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
    /*0008*/         NOP;                                  /* 0x4000000000001de4 */
    /*0010*/         MOV32I R3, 0x4;                       /* 0x180000001000dde2 */
    /*0018*/         S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;                   /* 0x2c00000094001c04 */
    /*0020*/         S2R R2, SR_TID.X;                     /* 0x2c00000084009c04 */
    /*0028*/         IMAD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;         /* 0x2004400020001ca3 */
    /*0030*/         SHL R6, R0, 0x2;                      /* 0x6000c00008019c03 */
    /*0038*/         IMAD R10.CC, R6, R3, c[0x0][0x20];    /* 0x2007800080629ca3 */
    /*0040*/         IMAD.HI.X R11, R6, R3, c[0x0][0x24];  /* 0x208680009062dce3 */
    /*0048*/         IMAD R2.CC, R6, R3, c[0x0][0x28];     /* 0x20078000a0609ca3 */
    /*0050*/         LD.E R4, [R10+0xc];                   /* 0x8400000030a11c85 */
    /*0058*/         IMAD.HI.X R3, R6, R3, c[0x0][0x2c];   /* 0x20868000b060dce3 */
    /*0060*/         LD.E R7, [R10+0x4];                   /* 0x8400000010a1dc85 */
    /*0068*/         LD.E R9, [R10+-0x4];                  /* 0x87fffffff0a25c85 */
    /*0070*/         LD.E R5, [R10+0x8];                   /* 0x8400000020a15c85 */
    /*0078*/         LD.E R0, [R10+0x10];                  /* 0x8400000040a01c85 */
    /*0080*/         LD.E R8, [R10];                       /* 0x8400000000a21c85 */
    /*0088*/         FADD R6, R7, R4;                      /* 0x5000000010719c00 */
    /*0090*/         FADD R4, R9, R7;                      /* 0x500000001c911c00 */
    /*0098*/         FADD R7, R5, R0;                      /* 0x500000000051dc00 */
    /*00a0*/         FADD R5, R8, R5;                      /* 0x5000000014815c00 */
    /*00a8*/         ST.E.128 [R2], R4;                    /* 0x9400000000211cc5 */
    /*00b0*/         EXIT;                                 /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
    ................................
```

All loads are 32-bit wide (`LD.E`). On the other side, there is just one store instruction `ST.E.128`, as expected.

I don't show the whole code here again, but I did a test where the stencil does not need a value to the left, but only one to the right (e.g. `*data + *(data+1)`), in which case my `values` array contains just 5 values and the `float4` load operation modifies the first 4 values of the array (I still have one extra load for the last value). In that case the compiler uses `LD.E.128`.

My question is why doesn't the compiler understand that it can use the 128-bit wide read if the target register is not the first one in the local array. After all the local array `values` is just a programming way to say that I need 6 floats to be stored in the registers. There is no such a thing like an array in the resulting ptx or SASS code. I thought I gave the compiler enough hints for it to understand `LD.E.128` was the right instruction here.

Second question: how can I make it use the 128-wide load here without having to manually write low-level code? (However if a couple of asm instructions help I'm open to receive suggestions.)

Side note: the decision of using 32-bit load for reading the input and 128-bit store for writing the input is taken while producing ptx code. ptx code already shows this pattern of multiple small loads and a single large store.

I am using CUDA 7.5 under linux.

---

Based on the suggestions given in the comments, I did some experiments.

Declaring either `input` or `output` as `__restrict__` (or both) solves the problem: the compiler generated a `LD.E.128` and two `LD.E`, which is what I wanted to achieve, when generating code for the architecture `sm_35`. Strangely enough, when generating for `sm_21` it still prduces six `LD.E`, but it produces one `ST.E.128`. It sounds like a compiler bug to me, because the instruction `LD.E.128` should be perfectly usable in the older architecture as it is in the newest.

The code presented above uses the 128-bit loads just with the small change of using the `__restrict__` keyword as suggested by njuffa and works. I did also follow the suggestion of m.s. I reproduced the same results shown in the pastebin snippet (one `LD.E.128` + one `LD.E.64`). But at runtime it crashes with the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  an illegal memory access was encountered
```

I'm pretty sure the misalignment is the cause of this problem.

Update: after using cuda-memcheck I'm sure the problem is misalignment:

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 16
=========     at 0x00000060 in kernel(float const *, float*, int)
=========     by thread (4,0,0) in block (7,0,0)
=========     Address 0xb043638bc is misaligned
```

Comment: Yes, you need the global vector where you load from to be naturally aligned. It is clear that CUDA assumes my output vector is naturally aligned (and it is). The input vector is also naturally aligned. In any case the compiler can take the same assumptions concerning both `input` and `output`.

Comment: No, they are 128-byes aligned. The thurst array is aligned to 128 bytes. I move forward by 32 float, so the pointer I pass to the kernel is 128-bytes aligned. Then I move forward by 4*(global thread Id), which is a multiple of 4 floats = 128 bits. The load must be aligned to a 128 bit boundary (= 4 bytes), and it is. Or am I misinterpreting some information? Anyway the very same applies to the output array, and there it works.

Comment: if you loads the first 4 values consecutively followed by two separate loads (`[i-1,i,i+1,i+2] [i+3] [i+4]`), you'll get the desired `LD.E.128` and even a `LD.E.64`: http://pastebin.com/MLrfmD4k; however this does not explain why your code does not work as expected

Comment: I also can't explain it; I think the compiler is having [more trouble generating vector loads lately](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/877259/cuda-programming-and-performance/mis-compile-causes-small-perf-issue-in-7-5-with-global-reads/) (CUDA 7.5).  In addition to the suggestion by @m.s. (which might be best -  performance and efficiency-wise) you can also modify your kernel code to not have the factor of 4 in your `i` variable, and then generate the necessary loads and stores using that.  It [seems to work for me](http://pastebin.com/TXRu88kZ).

Comment: @Spiros Why not simply pass `input` as `const float4* input` if 128-bit alignment is guaranteed by construction (the compiler cannot tell that when it compiles the kernel).

Comment: @njuffa when I did try this (and casted to `float*` for the two separate loads) the compiler did not generate a `LD.E.128`

Comment: @m.s. Puzzling. Interference from possible aliasing perhaps? Maybe try `const float4* __restrict__ input, float4* __restrict__ output`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the nvcc compiler is unable to resolve the base address for the vector load in your kernel. This can be a bug or is just an inadequacy.

I modified your code a little bit:

```
  __global__ void kernel2(const float* input, float* output, int size)
  {
      int i = (blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x);
      float values[6];
      float res[4];

      // Load values
      values[0] = *(input+(i*4)-1);
      float4 test  =*(reinterpret_cast<const float4*>(input)+i);
      values[5] = *(input+(i*4)+4);
      values[1] = test.x;
      values[2] = test.y;
      values[3] = test.z;
      values[4] = test.w;
      // Compute result
      res[0] = values[0]+values[2];
      res[1] = values[1]+values[3];
      res[2] = values[2]+values[4];
      res[3] = values[3]+values[5];

      // Store result
      *(reinterpret_cast<float4*>(output)+i) = *reinterpret_cast<const float4*>(res);
  }
```

The kernel code compiled to ptx:

```
  .visible .entry _Z7kernel2PKfPfi(
          .param .u64 _Z7kernel2PKfPfi_param_0,
          .param .u64 _Z7kernel2PKfPfi_param_1,
          .param .u32 _Z7kernel2PKfPfi_param_2
  )
  {
          .reg .f32       %f<15>;
          .reg .b32       %r<7>;
          .reg .b64       %rd<10>;
          ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z7kernel2PKfPfi_param_0];
          ld.param.u64    %rd2, [_Z7kernel2PKfPfi_param_1];
          mov.u32         %r1, %ntid.x;
          mov.u32         %r2, %ctaid.x;
          mov.u32         %r3, %tid.x;
          mad.lo.s32      %r4, %r2, %r1, %r3;
          shl.b32         %r5, %r4, 2;
          add.s32         %r6, %r5, -1;
          mul.wide.s32    %rd3, %r6, 4;
          cvta.to.global.u64      %rd4, %rd1;
          add.s64         %rd5, %rd4, %rd3;
          ld.global.f32   %f1, [%rd5];
          mul.wide.s32    %rd6, %r4, 16;
          add.s64         %rd7, %rd4, %rd6;
          ld.global.v4.f32        {%f2, %f3, %f4, %f5}, [%rd7];
          ld.global.f32   %f10, [%rd5+20];
          cvta.to.global.u64      %rd8, %rd2;
          add.s64         %rd9, %rd8, %rd6;
          add.f32         %f11, %f3, %f5;
          add.f32         %f12, %f2, %f4;
          add.f32         %f13, %f4, %f10;
          add.f32         %f14, %f1, %f3;
          st.global.v4.f32        [%rd9], {%f14, %f12, %f11, %f13};
          ret;
  }
```

You can see nicely how the addresses for the load are computed (%rd6 and %rd8).

While compiling your kernel to ptx results in:

```
  .visible .entry _Z6kernelPKfPfi(
          .param .u64 _Z6kernelPKfPfi_param_0,
          .param .u64 _Z6kernelPKfPfi_param_1,
          .param .u32 _Z6kernelPKfPfi_param_2
  )
  {
          .reg .f32       %f<11>;
          .reg .b32       %r<6>;
          .reg .b64       %rd<8>;
          ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z6kernelPKfPfi_param_0];
          ld.param.u64    %rd2, [_Z6kernelPKfPfi_param_1];
          cvta.to.global.u64      %rd3, %rd2;
          cvta.to.global.u64      %rd4, %rd1;
          mov.u32         %r1, %ntid.x;
          mov.u32         %r2, %ctaid.x;
          mov.u32         %r3, %tid.x;
          mad.lo.s32      %r4, %r2, %r1, %r3;
          shl.b32         %r5, %r4, 2;
          mul.wide.s32    %rd5, %r5, 4;
          add.s64         %rd6, %rd4, %rd5;
          ld.global.f32   %f1, [%rd6+-4];
          ld.global.f32   %f2, [%rd6];
          ld.global.f32   %f3, [%rd6+12];
          ld.global.f32   %f4, [%rd6+4];
          ld.global.f32   %f5, [%rd6+8];
          ld.global.f32   %f6, [%rd6+16];
          add.s64         %rd7, %rd3, %rd5;
          add.f32         %f7, %f5, %f6;
          add.f32         %f8, %f4, %f3;
          add.f32         %f9, %f2, %f5;
          add.f32         %f10, %f1, %f4;
          st.global.v4.f32        [%rd7], {%f10, %f9, %f8, %f7};
          ret;
  }
```

where the compiler only generates code to compute one address (%rd6) and uses static offsets. At this point the compiler failed to emit a vector load. Why? I honestly don't know, maybe two optimizations interfere here.

In SASS you see for `kernel2`:

```
        .section        .text._Z7kernel2PKfPfi,"ax",@progbits
        .sectioninfo    @"SHI_REGISTERS=18"
        .align  64
        .global         _Z7kernel2PKfPfi
        .type           _Z7kernel2PKfPfi,@function
        .size           _Z7kernel2PKfPfi,(.L_39 - _Z7kernel2PKfPfi)
        .other          _Z7kernel2PKfPfi,@"STO_CUDA_ENTRY STV_DEFAULT"
_Z7kernel2PKfPfi:
.text._Z7kernel2PKfPfi:
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x44];
        /*0010*/                   S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;
        /*0018*/                   MOV R4, c[0x0][0x140];
        /*0020*/                   S2R R3, SR_TID.X;
        /*0028*/                   MOV R5, c[0x0][0x144];
        /*0030*/                   IMAD R3, R0, c[0x0][0x28], R3;
        /*0038*/                   MOV32I R8, 0x10;
        /*0048*/                   IMAD R16.CC, R3, 0x10, R4;
        /*0050*/                   ISCADD R0, R3, -0x1, 0x2;
        /*0058*/                   IMAD.HI.X R17, R3, 0x10, R5;
        /*0060*/                   IMAD R14.CC, R0, 0x4, R4;
        /*0068*/                   IMAD.HI.X R15, R0, 0x4, R5;
        /*0070*/                   LD.E.128 R4, [R16];
        /*0078*/                   LD.E R2, [R14];
        /*0088*/                   IMAD R12.CC, R3, R8, c[0x0][0x148];
        /*0090*/                   LD.E R0, [R14+0x14];
        /*0098*/                   IMAD.HI.X R13, R3, R8, c[0x0][0x14c];
        /*00a0*/                   FADD R9, R4, R6;
        /*00a8*/                   FADD R10, R5, R7;
        /*00b0*/                   FADD R8, R2, R5;
        /*00b8*/                   FADD R11, R6, R0;
        /*00c8*/                   ST.E.128 [R12], R8;
        /*00d0*/                   EXIT;
.L_1:
        /*00d8*/                   BRA `(.L_1);
.L_39:
```

Here you have your `LD.E.128`.

Compiled with nvcc release 7.5, V7.5.17.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is, for which architecture did you compile? Can you compile your `kernel2` for sm_21? I remember applying exactly your approach (using a temporary variable and unpack it into the local array), and getting 6 separate loads.

Comment: I initially compiled for sm_35 but for sm_21 I get the same results.

Comment: Yes, me too. I must have done something wrong the first time. I can also compile with nvcc 6.5 and get the same results. Thanks a lot!